# service user name confusion

Tags: bug

I keep getting the little king and it's our fault message when posting on one (english) but not the other stack sites using the ostensibly same name. When moving from a permitted site, I find that my user name has changed. I can peruse and navigate but not post. What gives and who must pay attention in order to fix the problem or consilidate the two identities: 285_ _ and 284_ _? If I'm gonna spend time and resources, I had rather it not be going in circles.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of this "little king"?

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that you are unregistered on Bicycles and Home Improvement.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. Can you reword?

Comment: @simchona,Mitch: In the absence of a response from OP, I'm going to guess he means the SO [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) screen.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think that's quite right--I think the OP is seeing an error message where he can't post at all, not one that requires additional credentials.

Comment: was it like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5724095/images/oops%20cat.PNG)?

Comment: @cornbread ninja,simchona: oic. Perhaps OP has mistyped *king* instead of ***kitten***.

Answer (score 4):

You can link us to the various users here (make sure the emails match so we have some sort of verification) or send an email to team@stackexchange.com.  Either way we'll happily merge your accounts and fix you up.